# Mercurial clients and GitLab?

Tags: git, mercurial, gitlab

Is there a good way to let both git and hg clients use one repo system, like GitLab?

Pretty much like bitbucket. Should we just use https://hg-git.github.io/?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One (commercial) solution (developed by the same company behind [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/about)) is Kiln, which can managed a repo with Git or mercurial.
See [kiln Harmony](http://help.fogcreek.com/9212/getting-started-with-kiln-harmony).

If you use a git hosting service, then you need to manage a conversion system like hg-git yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You **must** use one SCM as "central", authoritative node, and another one, if it can communicate with first, as local repository.

As for Git+Mercurial you have two possibilities

- Hg-Git already mentioned (Git as upstream, Mercurial as local)
- [Bridge support in git for mercurial and bazaar](http://felipec.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/git-remote-hg-bzr-2/) (Mercurial as upstream, Git as local)

Answer (score -2):

In theory https://hg-git.github.io/ seems like a good approach for easing the migration from hg to git without having to change your build scripts.

I am wondering how many success stories we have with this approach. I propose to vote this answer up if you used it successfully or to vote down it if you tried and didn't work.